# clicking a link causes logo to move despite same code

Tags: html, css

It seems that jsfiddle does not let me use multiple html pages so i cannot post both pages. The issue is when i click a link my nav, i notice the logo move a little to the right instead of staying in the same place. the second html page has the exact same html code and css so i don't know why the logo would move once i click a link.

```
<header>
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">New York</a></h1>

        <nav class="main-navigation">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Does one page have a scroll bar?

Comment: yes the main home page does have a scroll bar.

Comment: Please put your index.html code here

Comment: I see what j08691 means now. The scroll bar on the first page takes extra space so if i don't have enough content to have a scroll on the second then that issue happens.